# What is the time source for Date()?

Tags: javascript, date

I can't manage to find what the source is for the JavaScript `Date()` method.

- Is it the time from the end user PC?
- Does it come from a global time server?

Comment: it comes from the operating system.

Comment: the machine on which your browser is running

Comment: @NinaScholz the standard does not require it to be from OS, it can be from anywhere including NTP

Comment: Is there any documentation? i didnt find any yet

Comment: Javascript is a client-side language, so it can't access to a server. That's self-explanatory.

Comment: @zerkms what? How javascript can get a time from a NTP ? You need to programming that, or no? What happens if there aren't a network connection in the machine?

Comment: @guiguiblitz an example of [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude the javascript specification may not explicitly state where to get the time from. Its implementation in a browser for example it may make no sense to get it from anywhere other than the system time. A javascript implementation on a web server (Node for example) might choose to get time from a NTP

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: What he said is that [the standard](https://es5.github.io/x15.9.html#x15.9.3.3) does not specify it: "The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to the time value (UTC) identifying the current time.". While all JS implementations that I know of take system time to be current time, it would be completely okay with EcmaScript standard to make an implementation of JS that fetches the time by NTP. It would not be very nice, as it would have to block while it does so (since `new Date()` is not asynchronous), but it conforms to the standard.

Comment: Ok, all clear now! Thank you for the new info :), but as I said, it's a client-side, so the date is getting from the browser, doesn't matter what service is called by the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The specification says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor):

> When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time (UTC).

Additionally, if you call the `Date` function as a constructor, [it says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor-date):

> ...the time value (UTC) identifying the current time

So in both cases, the specification says *"the current time"*.  It is up to the implementer (ie the browser) how it determines what "the current time" is, but it's *usually* driven by the time upon the device it is running.